# Scrapy Request are not crawling all urls return

Tags: python, scrapy

recently had this project of crawling google play store apps, for vietnam region, and realized that the request doesn't run the callback function for all URLs that haven been return.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl, urlencode
import scrapy


class GooglePlayStoreSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'google_play'
    allowed_domains = ['play.google.com']
    start_urls = ['http://play.google.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details')), follow=True,
             process_links='process_links',
             callback='parse_1'),
    )

    crawled_ids = []
    first_init = False

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        # print("-------------- PRINTING SECTION START_URL --------------")
        if not self.first_init:
            self.first_init = True
            extractor = LinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps/category/.*',))
            raw_links = extractor.extract_links(response)
            links = self.process_links(raw_links)
            return [
                scrapy.Request('{}'.format(link.url))
                for link in links
            ]
        else:
            # print("============ START_URL ELSE PART ============")
            pass

    def process_links(self, links):
        new_links = []
        for link in links:
            old_url = link.url

            if not old_url.startswith('https://play.google.com/store/apps/'):
                continue

            old_url_obj = urlparse(old_url)
            old_url_query = dict(parse_qsl(old_url_obj.query))

            if old_url_obj.path == '/store/apps/details':
                if old_url_query['id'] in self.crawled_ids:
                    continue
                else:
                    self.crawled_ids.append(old_url_query['id'])
            old_url_query['hl'] = 'en'
            old_url_query['gl'] = 'vn'
            link.url = '{}://{}{}?{}'.format(old_url_obj.scheme, old_url_obj.netloc, old_url_obj.path,
                                             urlencode(old_url_query))
            new_links.append(link)

        # print("LINKKSSS ====", links)
        # print("NEW_LINKKSSS ====", new_links)
        # print("-------------- PRINTING SECTION PROCESS_LINKS --------------")
        return new_links

    def parse_1(self, response):
        selector = scrapy.Selector(response)

        urls = selector.xpath('//a[@class="LkLjZd ScJHi U8Ww7d xjAeve nMZKrb  id-track-click "]/@href').extract()

        links = []
        for url in urls:
            if not url.startswith('https://play.google.com/'):
                url = "https://play.google.com" + url
            links.append(url)

        link_flag = 0

        for url in urls:
            # yield links_list.append(scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_next, dont_filter=True))
            yield Request(links[link_flag], callback=self.parse_next, dont_filter=True)
            link_flag += 1


    def parse_next(self, response):
        # print("PARSE_NEXT ===========", response.request.url)
        selector = scrapy.Selector(response)

        app_urls = selector.xpath('//div[@class="details"]/a[@class="title"]/@href').extract()

        urls = []
        for url in app_urls:
            url = "https://play.google.com" + url + '&hl=en&gl=vn'
            urls.append(url)

        url_list = []

        link_flag = 0

        for url in app_urls:
            yield Request(urls[link_flag], callback=self.parse_detail, dont_filter=True)
            link_flag += 1
        # return url_list

    def parse_detail(self, response):

        print("Parsed ======= ", response.request.url)

        item = dict()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['category'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="applicationCategory"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['review_score'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['review_count'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="reviewCount"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['link'] = response.request.url
        item['id'] = dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(response.request.url).query))['id']
        item['content_rating'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="contentRating"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['image'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="image"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract_first()
        item['price_currency'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]/@content').extract_first()
        # item['operating_system'] = response.xpath('//div[@itemscope]//meta[@itemprop="operatingSystem"]/@content').extract_first()
        return item
```

As i run into the terminal, it says that it crawled 100 pages and scraped only 15 pages, (numbers are for estimate).
Please help

Comment: Are the urls that are skipped duplicates or not matching your requirements to be scraped? Only links from `https://play.google.com` with the path `store/apps/details` and unique is are being parsed.

Comment: I printed out the links are returned to the parse_detail, all the links are from https://play.google.com with the path store/apps/details, some of them are being return more than twice also..

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve